# How can I build a stemmer on my own given I have a huge list of words and a list of almost all possible inflections in that language

Tags: python, natural-language

I have a dataset of close to 26,000 distinct words and I have also extracted close to 136 word-inflections possible from them.

How do I build a stemmer on my own without using any library as such with the help of the above two resources? I have already implemented a Dictionary Lookup method and I am looking for a more algorithmic approach. Note: It is a non-English language.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use Naive Bayes with the characters as features? You could also implement a character level BiLSTM for better accuracy.